# Exiting a function from a function called within

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have this function that takes a string and either returns a string or None

```
from typing import Union

def ret_str(name: str) -> Union[str, NoneType]:
    if name.lower() == 'zz':
        return "Zzz"
    else:
        return None
```

Now I have another function that uses `ret_str` to print some stuff

```
from module import ret_str

def processing():
    s = input("Name?: ")

    new = ret_str

    if not new:
        return 
    
    print(new)
```

How could I make it so, that within the `ret_str` function, if the return value is None, I can exit the processing function (the function that it was called within) from the ret_str function. Instead of having to add

```
if not new:
    return
```

in the `processing` function

Comment: You can't. Raising an exception would technically exit anything that isn't an try block, but that don't do that. Just do what you re doing already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper way to exit the function from the stack. But you can throw an exception from the `ret_str` function and handle it in the place where you call `processing`.